# titanium apk in samsung galaxy tab 2.2 results in error

Tags: android, titanium, apk, samsung-mobile

When I run my titanium application in android emulator it runs fine, but when I run the same apk in my samsung galaxy tab, then it got force closed. I have taken the apk from the source\bin folder. Please share the steps of installing and running titanium apk into the device. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Delete bin folder, rebuild, clean, maybe compile unsigned (right click project -> android tools, from eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

I still prefer to use titanium developer tool instead of studio and it's still working fine for me. So if you tab is in development mode than i think you just have to click one button "Install Now" from Run on Device part. In android it will directly install your app to your tab.

That's it you have to do. No need to take APk from build and install manually.